# How are the values of the ARMA process linked in python

Tags: programming, time-series, machine-learning, arima

In the code below, you can see that 'ret' is an ARMA process, and I am trying to see how the ret[0], etc... ret3, ret4, etc. are linked to each other, and although I know the formula for the ARMA process (see it below) , I cannot manually reproduce e.g ret[4] from the previous values... Any help?

[image]

[image]

I tried to reproduce it as below, but it does not give ret[4]

[image]

Below you can find the code in text:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(200)

ar_params = np.array([1, -0.5])
ma_params = np.array([1, -0.3])

print(ar_params)
print(ma_params)

from statsmodels.tsa.arima_process import ArmaProcess

length = 5 * 252   
np.random.seed(200)
ret = ArmaProcess(ar_params, ma_params).generate_sample(nsample=length)

ret = pd.Series(ret)
print('========================')
print("\nret = ", ret) ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that $\epsilon_t \sim N(0,1)$ is a white noise process and the random variates are simulated from a standard normal distribution. Hence, it does not make sense for you to multiply `ret[2]` and `ret[3]` with the MA-parameters, in order to reproduce `ret[4]`.

#### The source code reveals how to reproduce the simulation values of the ARMA process:

From the source code of the *ArmaProcess().generate_sample()* function (see [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/tsa/arima_process.py#L44)), you will find that it effectively uses the filter algorithm from the scipy package called *signal.lfilter()*. The signal filter from the scipy package, can be defined as (again, see this [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html)):

\begin{equation}
\phi_0 \cdot y_t = \theta_0 \epsilon_t + \theta_{1} \epsilon_{t-1} + \ldots+\theta_{q} \epsilon_{t-q} - \phi_1 y_{t-1} - \ldots - \phi_p y_{t-p} ,
\end{equation}
where $p$ and $q$ refers to the number of lagged terms in the filter algorithm. One way of transforming the above filter algorithm to an ARMA(p,q) process is simply to set $\phi_0 = \theta_0 = 1$ and negate the rest of the phi's. Both of these things are also noted in the documentation of the *ArmaProcess().generate_sample()* function, which is the reason why your above code contains 1's in the first entry of the `ar_params` and `ma_params`. Now, we can observe that the above code simulates an ARMA(1,1) process and assuming that you have already negated the AR-parameter, $\phi_1$, then `ret[4]` ($y_4$) can be found via:
\begin{equation}
y_4= \epsilon_4 + (- 0.3) \cdot \epsilon_{3}  - y_{3} \cdot (-0.5) = 0.5 \cdot y_3 - 0.3 \cdot \epsilon_3 + \epsilon_4. 
\end{equation}
I have provided some Python code that recovers the *ArmaProcess().generate_sample()* simulation using the *signal.lfilter()* method, which can be seen below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc

np.random.seed(200)
whitenoise = np.random.normal(size=length)
test = sc.signal.lfilter(ma_params, ar_params, whitenoise)
test = pd.Series(test)
test
```

[image: sec code]

From your own code (or you could've used *test*) and the above described equation, we can manually calculate `ret[4]`:

```
ret4 =  ma_params[0] * whitenoise[4]  + ma_params[1] * whitenoise[3] - ret[3] * ar_params[1]
ret4
```

[image: last code]

I encourage you to read the documentation of the *signal.lfilter()* function to further understand how the algorithm initializes etc. However, this should be the gist of it. I hope this provide some guidance.